# Rails lost migration file issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations

2 months ago, one of my migration files has been removed. The thing is when I rake db:migrate my database in localhost the migration is missing. I can Not create a new migration because the production database was migrated with the missing file. So everytime I import the production database in local and I run a migration it says:

***Field already exists....***

I saw some comment which says I should modify the schema_migrations table with the corresponding version of the migration file.

Do you have any deeper explanation about this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the schema_migrations table holds all the version numbers of all the migrations that have been run, or that the system thinks have been run at least.  When you do `rake db:migrate`, rails looks at all the files in db/migrate, and ignores the ones whose numerical prefix is in `schema_migrations`.

So, if you have a migration that has actually already been run, but the system thinks it hasn't, you just need to add its version number into schema_migrations.

Open the relevant database console, and type

```
insert into schema_migrations (version) values("<the number from the start of the migration file>");
```

obviously, replace the part in < > with the proper number.

Then, db:migrate will no longer try and run that migration.